# dup2 which copies instead of redirecting

Tags: c++

I have the following at the start of my code to redirect the stdout to a file. Instead of redirecting the strings sent to stdout to the file instead, I wish for the strings to be sent to **both** stdout and the file. How do I do this from within my code?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int file = open("out.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);
    if(file < 0)    return 1;
    if(dup2(file,1) < 0)    return 1;
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Please not that my code is using printf and other c functions for writing to the stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a pipe to `tee`, then write to that.

```
// be careful to quote the file argument properly!
FILE *fp = popen("tee out.txt", "w");
```

You can't get the behavior you want at the file descriptor or stdio levels in a POSIX system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with `printf`, I can only see two possibilities: either print to stdout only and use the `tee` utility to also write everything to a file externally, or write a wrapper around `printf` which calls `printf` twice, once for writing to a file and once for writing to stdout (and for every other c function you use in your code to print to stdout). You cannot do what you want using just `dup`/`dup2`.